# Can we create custom TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I just started learning Android Development and wanted to know that is there a way to make TextViews more creative. Like can we apply gradient filter or add shadows to it.

I tried using some background color and other properties.

Comment: Reminder that searching before asking is desirable: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+textview+gradient Otherwise you should show what code you used and an image of what you are getting with that code and what you are trying to achieve. Without code readers can't tell specifically what you want.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use shadows in TextView:

```
android:shadowColor="#636363"
android:shadowDx="2"
android:shadowDy="2"
android:shadowRadius="10"
android:background="@drawable/temp"
```

- The shadowColor property allows you to change the color of the
  shadow.
- The shadowDx property allows you to change the vertical placement of
  the shadow.
- The shadowDy property allows you to change the horizental placement
  of the shadow.
- The shadowRadius property allows you to increase the amount of area
  where the shadow is shown.

And as for the background, we first need to create a shape that has the appearance we want and we can apply that shape appearance onto the TextView.

To do so, we first make a new xml file (Drawable Resource File) in the drawable folder which is found under the "res" folder.

You can find more information about android xml shapes online but here's a simple example of a rectangular shape that has a linear gradient background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#f6ee19"
        android:endColor="#115ede" />
    <corners
        android:radius="6dp"/>
</shape>
```

You can apply this shape by adding the android:background="@drawable/custom_shape" attribute to your TextView. (You need to rename custom_shape to the name you chose for the xml file)